# Why do I get "Documents: No such file or directory" on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, files, directory, users

I have just installed Ubuntu Server, but I cannot use it because it seems like I do not have any files, not even a `Documents` directory. Do you have any idea why I cannot see any files?

```
talina@DESKTOP:~$ pwd
/home/talina
talina@DESKTOP:~$ ls
talina@DESKTOP:~$ cd Documents
-bash: cd: Documents: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you install the "Desktop" (GUI) version of Ubuntu - or the "Server" version?

Comment: Try `ls -al` to see any hidden files. And basically the same Q as steeldriver, is there a GUI? Did you create the talina user yourself, with `adduser` or `useradd`, or did the installer?

Comment: @Xen2050 it does not change anything when i use ls -al. 
 I am using the server version. I created the username during the installation; Ubuntu asked me for a user name and a password

Comment: The Documents, Downloads etc. directories are not populated in Ubuntu server installs - you can create any directories you wish manually using the `mkdir` command

Answer (score 2):

[This comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128409/documents-no-such-file-or-directory#comment1868253_1128409) by steeldriver explains this

> The Documents, Downloads etc. directories are not populated in Ubuntu server installs.

You [said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128409/documents-no-such-file-or-directory#comment1868243_1128409) you are using the server version, so these directories being absent is expected.

> you can create any directories you wish manually using the `mkdir` command

For example

```
mkdir ~/Documents
```